# How to uninstall properly svn package in cygwin

Tags: svn, cygwin, uninstallation

I need to install a svn client on Windows 10. 
The svn I used is inside Cygwin and makes wron path problems so I would like to uninstall the svn package properly inside Cygwin before to install another one.
I would like to keep Cygwin so...
How can I uninstall properly the svn package without uninstall Cygwin ?

Answer (score 1):

`svn` belongs to the `subversion` package, as cygcheck reports

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/svn
subversion-1.11.0-1
```

Cygwin `setup-ARCH.exe`allows to uninstall packages.
Select `Full` view, search for `subversion` in the name and all relevant packages will be filtered. Some have `Keep` and other with `Skip` in the Column `New`.
Klick on every `Keep` location multiple time until `Uninstall` will appear.

[image]

The next version of `Setup` has a more clear menu to select the `Uninstall`
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-10/msg00167.html

[image]

Comment: I´m using cygwin 2.10.0(0.325/5/3), I tried to find `setup-ARCH.exe` without success.

Comment: You have not mentioned if you are using 32 or 64 bit version. So it is or  `setup-x86.exe` or  `setup-x86_64.exe` used for installing cygwin https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Yes, sorry. It´s the cygwin 64 bits version.

Comment: I searched and see all .exe without success.

Comment: It is not in the cygwin directory. It is the program used to install cygwin. You can download again from https://www.cygwin.com/